# Does any terminal multiplexer (screen, tmux, zellij) support job suspension (Ctrl-Z) in Bash?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, background-process, job-control, terminal-multiplexer

As far as I've seen, pressing Ctrl-Z on any terminal multiplexer, or trying to start them in the background, does nothing or crashes.

I know that, in a sense, terminal multiplexers are a "replacement" for job control, and usually, they have their own mechanisms for suspending and resuming. Still, I was wondering if I could integrate them in some way into a workflow based on the shell's job control.

**Answer:**

- Screen suspends with "C-a z"
- Tmux suspends with "C-b C-z"
- Zellij suspends with "C-o d", but unlike the previous ones, it doesn't place the process on the shell's job control.

Comment: I kinda doubt it, since ^Z usually suspends the process, and you don't want to actually stop something like `screen`, since it needs to be live to allow you to attach from elsewhere, or indeed to read the output of anything running inside it. Though I suppose it could be made to react to the stop signal by detaching itself, but then you couldn't get it back with `fg` anyway since it wouldn't be there. Plus there's the issue of how you're going to send the ^Z to the terminal multiplexer, since it usually just passes it to whatever you're running inside it. But I don't know, so not an answer.

Comment: > "Plus there's the issue of how you're going to send the ^Z to the terminal multiplexer..."

I guess it would be possible to react to the `suspend` command, or to ^Z when it happens on the top level. But yes, look like in general this is not possible.

Comment: what top level? If you mean the shell running inside multiplexer, I don't think it's at all simple for the terminal (emulator / multiplexer) to know what's running inside the terminal, as it has no part in starting the processes there or passing along the file descriptor to the "client side" of the terminal to the various processes. (Consider that a terminal is a dumb computer on the other end of a UART connection, it only receives and sends characters and has no idea of the logic going on in the other end.)

Comment: Interesting, but I guess there should be some mechanism by which the multiplexer can intercept keys in some way. Actually, I just found out that you can indeed suspend from screen and tmux, but you need to use other key combinations ("C-a z" in screen, "C-b C-z" in tmux). Not sure how I missed that before.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just that it's hard for the multiplexer to know what's running inside it, so hard to capture the keys in a context-sensitive way. I thought you knew about their own magic keys since you mentioned the multiplexers having their own mechanisms. Anyway, there's also `screen -d -m` for starting one directly in a detached state (in the background). I don't know about the equivalent in tmux, though.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew there were mechanisms to suspend, but I didn't realize that they integrate into the shell's Job Control, which is what I wanted. And Zellij's suspend mechanism (C-o d) doesn't integrate with Job Control. Anyway, thanks for your help. This answers the question.

Comment: "C-o d" sounds suspiciously similar to screen's "C-a d" aka detach

Comment: ah yes of course, I was just thinking about the usual detaching even though "C-a z" is of course different. Sorry.

Comment: If you think the "answer" part is an answer then it should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to suspend a job inside a `screen` window?

- Just use <kbd>Ctrl z</kbd> inside the screen window (as usual). This doesn't suspend `screen`, though.

Do you want to suspend `screen` itself?

- Use <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> inside any screen window. But notice that although this suspends the user-facing part of the `screen` application, it doesn't suspend the applications being managed through `screen`. This is because `screen` is designed that its user-facing part can be detached with <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, and the managed processes continue to run.

Answer (score 1):

#### tmux

> Tmux suspends with "C-b C-z"

… i.e. <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (the default prefix is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>).

You can tell it to suspend the client with sole <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. This is a command for a shell inside tmux:

```
tmux bind-key -T root C-z suspend-client
```

But then you will lose the ability to suspend a process inside tmux with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. It's now sane to make <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> just send `^Z` and let the "inner" tty handle it:

```
tmux bind-key -T prefix C-z send-keys C-z
```

This way we have swapped the default functionality of <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in tmux.

---

Inside `.tmux.conf` the commands will be:

```
bind-key -T root C-z suspend-client
bind-key -T prefix C-z send-keys C-z
```